# Error: Attribute "title" has already been defined

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I want to add 2 or more Library into my project.

1. Actionbar
2. Actionbar Sherlock
3. Facebook SDK
4. google-play-sevices
5. Date picker library

I added this library into my project but i getting **error** like.

**D:\workspace\workspace\actionbarsherlock\res\values\abs__attrs.xml:209: error: Attribute "title" has already been defined**

I think here problem with Actionbar & Actionbar Sherlock library in same name of **title** but i don't know how to fix this.

Please tell me how to fix that.

Comment: Why Actionbar & Actionbar Sherlock?

Comment: Custom define Actionbar So used Actionbar & Actionbar Sherlok @UdiOshi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actionbar Sherlock is a library project, i think you can edit "title" in abs__attrs.xml and call it something else "title1"! so don't forget to replace all title occurrences by CMD+R or find eclipse function.

Comment: This surely is a solution, but what if you've got 100 of these occurrences? (also mentioned here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/adt-dev/HeM0aptfddY/R8a18AwE7MQJ)

Answer (score 3):

If you have the source code and don't want to change their original's name, the following is a alternative solution:
1.declare the defined attr at the begin of xml file instead of in one  set.
2. reference the declared attr without format (it's already defined in step 1, don't defined again) inside of one  set.

Now it's done. Here is an sample.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <attr name="icon" format="integer" />
   <declare-styleable name="PreferenceHeader" >
      <!-- Identifier value for the header. -->
      < attr name="id" format="integer"/>
      < attr name="icon" />
  </declare-styleable >

  <declare-styleable name="Preference" >
      < attr name= "icon"/>
      <!-- The key to store the Preference value. -->
      < attr name="key" format ="string" />
  </declare-styleable >
</resources>
```